# listenTo não ouve sua respectiva trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Tenho várias outros listenTo que respondem de maneira correta ao seu trigger, porem essa abaixo não está respondendo, já tentei de todas as formas fazer ela responder, porem todas as tentativas foram sem sucesso.

```
addFotoPrincipal: function(){
            app.vent.trigger('fotoPrincipal');
        },

this.listenTo(app.vent, 'fotoPrincipal', function(){
            console.log('teste');
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei o erro, o que acontece é que o listenTo está em um arquivo que não está ligado de nenhuma maneira ao trigger e a view onde o listenTo está não está carregada na memória, assim o listenTo nunca irá ouvir o trigger.